# "Inlining" a zsh function

Tags: zsh

In my .zshrc, I have this function definition, it prints out vim history and opens chosen file in vim:

```
vim_hist() {
    n=$(sed -n "s|~|$HOME|;s|^> \(.*\)|\1|p" ~/.vim/viminfo | fzf)
    [ "$n" != "" ] && [ -f "$n" ] && vim $n
}
```

And this is declaration in .zshrc:

```
zle -N VH vim_hist
bindkey '^a' VH
```

And when i enter `vim_hist` in my shell, everything works fine. But, when I do the `CTRL-A`, i get warning `Vim: Warning: Input is not from terminal`, which makes command significantly slower. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the doc (`info zsh widgets`):

> User-defined widgets, being implemented as shell functions, can execute
> any normal shell command.  They can also run other widgets (whether
> built-in or user-defined) using the zle builtin command.  **The standard
> input of the function is redirected from /dev/null to prevent external
> commands from unintentionally blocking ZLE by reading from the terminal**,
> but read -k or read -q can be used to read characters.  Finally, they
> can examine and edit the ZLE buffer being edited by reading and setting
> the special parameters described below.

Here, you can *undo* that by doing:

```
vim_hist() {
    n=$(sed -n "s|~|$HOME|;s|^> \(.*\)|\1|p" ~/.vim/viminfo | fzf)
    if [ "$n" != "" ] && [ -f "$n" ]; then
        vim < /dev/tty $n
        zle -I
    fi
}
```

(also calling `zle -I` to invalidate the prompt so it be redrawn upon return of `vim`)

Comment: sorry for necroposting, but I don't really understand what is happening here. "The standard input of the function is redirected from /dev/null" does it mean stdin of function call is usually /dev/null and zsh prevents it from happening? And I dont really understand why? And where did we get tty suddenly from?

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic, zsh makes sure the ZLE widgets have their stdin open on /dev/null, so that if they ever read anything from their stdin, it doesn't interfere with input from the terminal and just returns nothing. Here we do want our widget (vim) to take over tty input from zle, so we're reopening the controlling tty device for vim's stdin.